# Why do I not have access to App.xaml.cs from other classes in my app?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, bing-maps, sealed, app.xaml

I'm trying to declare a global var in App.xaml.cs this way:

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    public static string SessionKey { get; set; }
    . . .
```

I added a "Loaded" event to the map in MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
    <bm:Map x:Name="galaxyMap" Credentials="ImpeccableOrPerhapsALittleBitPeccable" 
Margin="0,0,0,0" MapType="Birdseye" Loaded="galaxyMap_OnLoaded" >
```

...which event gets the Session Key, assigning it to the global var:

```
async private void galaxyMap_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        App.SessionKey = await visitsMap.GetSessionIdAsync();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

However, when I try to access that value when making a REST call:

```
String httpqry = String.Format(
    "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?addressLine={0}&locality={1}&postalCode=
{2}&adminDistrict={3}&countryRegion={4}&key={5}",
    addrElements[STREET_ADDRESS], addrElements[LOCALITY], addrElements[POSTAL_CODE], 
addrElements[ST8_PROVINCE], addrElements[COUNTRY]), 
    App.SessionKey)
```

...I get a red "SessionKey" and on the dot between "App" and "SessionKey" it says, "*Invalid expression term '.'*"

-and: "*; expected*" in the same place, and "*Invalid expression term ')'*" on the ")" at the end of the call to String.Format().

Why is "App" unrecognized? The class where these errors occur is in the same namespace. Why wouldn't it see the application instance?

Comment: Do you need to make it `public` like `public sealed partial class App`

Comment: Good thought, but no, that makes no difference. Besides, "App" is recognized from within MainPage.xaml.cs -- the OnLoaded() event sees it just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a syntax error. There is one ')' too much:

> addrElements[COUNTRY])

This ')' should be removed.

Comment: Billy Crudup, you're right! I hate it when that happens!